# Rotating object to axis

Tags: modifiers

Is there a way to rotate my object such that it matches perfectly with the axis? I'm trying to mirror a spherical object but the mirrored product is always off due to (what I suspect to be) rotational issues. I'm new to blender and I've been struggling with this for hours, any help would be welcome

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just fixed image embedding in your post. Please take some time to understand how to use the question editor image tool. Btw, don't take photos of your monitor, it's not very clear and also complicated, take a screenshot instead (https://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Screenshot-in-Microsoft-Windows)

Comment: About your issue, it's not very clear what you mean, so add details about which exact operations are you performing on the mirrored object, and  add a screenshot of what happens

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use spin for this check out this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRgcXnd1Wl4